# Kivy buttons don't work when launching app with 'sudo python'

Tags: python, permissions

So I was having a permissions problem earlier and was going through different methods to try and solve it. Ultimately I solved the issue, but now the buttons in my Kivy app no longer work when pressed on the touchscreen when I run the app with 'sudo python'. If I run the app with just 'python' the buttons work as normal. I suspect that I fudged up some permissions or ownership somewhere along the line that is not giving root all of the necessary things it needs to make kivy buttons work.

I used chown -R pi /home/pi  &  chmod -R u+rwX /home/pi earlier and I thought this may be a problem so I tried chown -R root /home/pi, but it didn't make a difference. I couldn't even import the kivy module without adding a line in /etc/sudoers:

```
Defaults    env_keep += "PYTHONPATH"
```

The app runs when using sudo, just no button functionality. Is there a way to fix this without having to reinstall everything?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: I ended up reinstalling everything, but I have the same issue. Not sure how I was able to run sudo python before, but I need it inorder to access a file when running my app.

Comment: "I suspect that I fudged up some permissions or ownership somewhere along the line that is not giving root all of the necessary things" - um, `root` doesn't need permission to do things - that is why that account is called the *super*user one.  What can keep even someone with those powers out of things is either encryption keys or "cookies" that they don't possess (the latter is sometimes used by the X system to protect X data between client {application} and server {screen}).  Perhaps the touch-screen is locked to the `pi` user by the XServer and inaccessible to the sudoed python prog!

Comment: Yes, you're right about root. I read that you shouldn't use 'sudo' because the touch screen uses 'probesysfs' when configuring Kivy to use the touch screen as an input source. So, I guess it is not possible to open access restricted files from within a Kivy app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user zeeMonkeez supplied an answer to my problem. What he said is this:

I'd suggest a different approach: make

```
/sys/class/backlight/rpi-backlight/bl_power
```

writable to the user running the Python script (most likely pi). Temporarily, this can be done with

```
sudo chmod a+w /sys/class/backlight/rpi_backlight/bl_power
```

(this grants write rights to all users). But this will also be reset at the next restart. The solution for that is to write a udev rule. They live in

```
/etc/udev/rules.d
```

and on my system, 99-com.rules was a good starting point. Here is what I have in a file called 98-backlight.rules:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="backlight", PROGRAM="/bin/sh -c 'chown -R root:video /sys/class/backlight && chmod -R 770 /sys/class/backlight; chown -R root:video /sys/devices/platform/rpi_backlight && chmod -R 770 /sys/devices/platform/rpi_backlight'"
```

This changes the owner group to video and grants group write rights. User pi is by default member of video. Then all you need is a restart (or sudo udevadm control --reload-rules followed by sudo udevadm trigger) to activate the new rule.

Comment: You can set ownership(OWNER, GROUP) and mode(MODE) with udev rules directly, so there's no need for a PROGRAM statement.